# Range select between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, range

I have an Oracle 11g and I want to know if it is possible to make a select from a date to another date.

For example:
I have two fields called `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I want to show the count of rows between `EndDate` and `StartDate`.
If my `StartDate` is `2018-08-01` and my `EndDate` is `2018-08-10` so my expected table should be:

```
DATE       | rownum
2018-08-01 | 1
2018-08-02 | 2
2018-08-03 | 3
2018-08-04 | 4
2018-08-05 | 5
2018-08-06 | 6
2018-08-07 | 7
2018-08-08 | 8
2018-08-09 | 9
2018-08-10 | 10
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "show the count of rows"? The count of rows is 10; you show something very different in the "expected table". We can't help you if your problem description is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a row generator like the following:

```
select date '2018-08-01' + level -1 as yourDate,
       level as yourRowNum
from dual
connect by date '2018-08-01' + level -1 <= date '2018-08-10'
```

The result:

```
YOURDATE   YOURROWNUM
---------- ----------
2018-08-01          1
2018-08-02          2
2018-08-03          3
2018-08-04          4
2018-08-05          5
2018-08-06          6
2018-08-07          7
2018-08-08          8
2018-08-09          9
2018-08-10         10
```

To avoid repeating the date values, you can use:

```
with dateRange(startDate, endDate) as
(
    select date '2018-08-01', date '2018-08-10'
    from dual
)
select startDate + level -1 as yourDate,
       level as yourRowNum
from dateRange
connect by startDate + level -1 <= endDate;
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksej! It was very useful! I had to change somethings, but this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You may easily get what you'd like by using  `sum(1) over (order by "date")`:

```
select "Date", sum(1) over (order by "Date") "Row Number"
  from tab 
 where "Date" between date'2018-08-01' and date'2018-08-10';

Date         Row Number
----------   ----------       
2018-08-01          1
2018-08-02          2
2018-08-03          3
2018-08-04          4
2018-08-05          5
2018-08-06          6
2018-08-07          7
2018-08-08          8
2018-08-09          9
2018-08-10         10
```

Other alternatives `count(1)`, `row_number()` might be replaced with `sum(1)`, also.

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fec94b/7)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this...

```
WITH my_table AS
    (SELECT     TRUNC(SYSDATE) + LEVEL - 1 AS current_day
     FROM       DUAL
     CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(current_day) OVER (ORDER BY current_day) first_day
     , current_day
     , current_day - FIRST_VALUE(current_day) OVER (ORDER BY current_day) days_diff
FROM   my_TABLE;

FIRST_DAY CURRENT_DAY  DAYS_DIFF
--------- ----------- ----------
29-AUG-18 29-AUG-18            0
29-AUG-18 30-AUG-18            1
29-AUG-18 31-AUG-18            2
29-AUG-18 01-SEP-18            3
29-AUG-18 02-SEP-18            4
29-AUG-18 03-SEP-18            5
29-AUG-18 04-SEP-18            6
29-AUG-18 05-SEP-18            7
29-AUG-18 06-SEP-18            8

9 rows selected.
```